# How do I delete the Edit Delete buttons suddenly showing above pictures?

Tags: 7, media

All of a sudden when I insert a picture into a page, it shows an edit and a delete button above the image to the end user.  These buttons take you to the default page.  Also, now when I edit a page from the edit button at the top of each page and save, I get the following type of message after a lengthy wait.

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 356515840 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 523800 bytes) in /data/www/luna/sites/all/modules/token/token.module on line 767

I can edit and save if I select the page under Content.

See http://lunahq.com/content/luna-rox-v8-simple-smarter

Comment: Thx but I don't think that will get rid of the Edit and Delete buttons?  I'm pretty sure the image and the memory problem are related.

Answer (score 0):

you need to increase the memory limit size in php.ini

That indicates that Drupal needed more memory than PHP was allowed to give it.

Drupal 7

> ```
> Memory increase to 128M:
> (This has worked every-time; and used to always work for D6 as well)
>
> Create a new file php.ini, and add the code...
> php_value memory_limit = "128M"
> and put that file in your Drupal 7 (or D6) root folder.
>     For step-by-step details, see comment below...
>     Drupal 7 "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of ...".
> If you need more than 128M:
>
> Add the line
> ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
> to your [Drupal 7 root]/sites/default/settings.php file.
>
> I have yet to need this much memory, but I did achieve
> a memory increase to 512M using this slightly more complicated
> process that involved temporarily changing the permission level
> for that file.
>     For step-by-step details see the comment below Drupal 7 memory increase to more than 128M.
> ```

refer this link

https://www.drupal.org/node/76156